# DevExpress TreeList

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to show my `TreeList` with Lines as shown in the below figure :
[image: <code>TreeList</code> Nodes with <code>+and-</code>]

Answer (score 0):

Set the [TreeListSettings.ShowTreeLines](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListTreeListSettings_ShowTreeLinestopic) to display ASPxTreeLis lines.
Note: Some themes (such as the 'DevExpress Style' or all 'Office 2010' themes) are engineered in such a way that by design they are not intended to display tree lines and grid lines within the ASPxTreeList.

You can read more about tree lines and their styles here: [Tree Lines](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3988)
Ralated Demo: [Appearance Customization - Grid Lines and Tree Lines](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/Appearance/GridLinesTreeLines.aspx)